# I am using pandas in python to read a csv,how do I pass a sheet name to read particular sheet

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using pandas in python to read a .csv file ,how do I pass a sheet name to the function pandas.read_csv() so I can read data from a particular sheet. The code used  is :

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

How do I pass the sheet name as an argument?????

Comment: Didnt `pd.read_csv("filename.csv") ` work?  Official documentation - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: It worked but I have multiple sheets in the file and I only want to read a particular sheet.

Answer (score 12):

CSV file is as comma seperated file and so there is no concept of multiple sheets.
Try

```
pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Following [link](https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/5927/read-a-specific-sheet) might help.

Comment: `sheet_name` in pandas v1.2.3

Comment: sheetname/sheet_name, neither of them works.

Comment: what is your pandas version ?